# What is important in a mobile application ? Memory optimization or fast execution

Tags: java, android, memory, time

This is an open question towards learning about memory optimization and code optimization for faster execution. What would you give more importance within the two ?

How do you usually optimize you code to use memory efficiently ?

How do you optimize your code to run faster ?

As a mobile developer we've to give importance to use memory properly. But sometimes using it usually backfires by creating more objects or under utilizing the memory.

What are your usual methods to optimize memory & decrease the run time of the application ?

Comment: This question is overly broad IMO, the answer depends on your priorities.

Comment: I agree the question is from a broad perspective. Methods like async task reduce time factor. Even using a hashmap for comparisons is considered faster. What I wanted to know are there any more efficient methods to make the code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult to answer question. There is no general answer to this question, it depends on your priorities. For some apps(chess programs) it is the efficiency, for some apps(gallery app) it is the memory usage that is more important. However, more often than not, neither of these could be a bottleneck. In such cases, you should choose the cleanest and easiest to maintain way.

However in my experience, most of the time it is the memory that cause the bottleneck(if there is one at all) on Android. On `StackOverflow`, everyday I see some posts about `OutOfMemory` errors and I rarely see a `my app is running too slow` post.

Here are some specific tips that come to my mind:

**1)** Call

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

whenever the `bitmap` is not needed. This could release the memory earlier.

**2)**
Try to avoid file access as much as possible. Using a SQLite db can help you achieve that in a more efficient way.

**3)**
Don't leak memory. Use memory management tools that come with eclipse to track those leaks.

**4)**
Hand big files in chunks, and small files without chunks!

**5)**
Check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) on "android memory management". It gives plenty of useful information.

Also there is similar discussion here: [Memory efficiency vs Processor efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977829/memory-efficiency-vs-processor-efficiency) (note that it is not specifically for android)

Answer (score 0):

The two are not mutually exclusive.   Efficient code WILL run faster and use less memory.  Period.

Comment: -1 There are many cases where you cannot achieve both. For example image/video compression. Or imagine there is a 100MB file you need to process. You can load and process the file at once(= faster, high memory usage), or chunk by chunk(= slower, low memory usage)

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS - you're splitting hairs.  There are of course things that just require a lot of memory, but that doesn't mean the code cannot be written efficiently.  As a rule of thumb, developers should make every attempt to write efficient code that runs fast with low memory usage.  How could you possibly argue that point?

Comment: I don't argue that. I argue against "The two are `NOT` mutually exclusive" & "Efficient code `WILL` run faster and use less memory." Just put "Usually" in the beginning of your answer and I agree with you 100% :)

Comment: I thinkSBerg413 is right here. Exceptions are always there but they should not be generalized as question asked here is for general mobile application so answer we can post in general terms.

Comment: @SBerg413 Actually, an optimal algorithm gives you the best execution time for some input X. However in many many cases, manipulating the size of the input can make the algorithm perform better. Voted for closing the question.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS - Again, you're splitting hairs.  For your comment "There are many cases where you cannot achieve both" I would remove the word "many" and replace it with "some" or "a few". ;O)

Comment: I insist that the answer is not clear cut, and there many such cases that it is hard to call those `exceptions`. I guess we need to agree to disagree. By the way more on this discussion, pls check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977829/memory-efficiency-vs-processor-efficiency

Comment: Code can be optimized for speed, for resource consumption, or both. There's almost always a tradeoff; only rarely will optimizing for both end up being the fastest, or have the lowest resource consumption.